# build vba code to reflect last transactions done

Tags: excel, vba

this table is about bank transactions
i want to build vba code that return last transaction done, its date and code

**last transaction done is the last row in the table meet the required criteria**

## the criterias are as following

`input name = name in the col D input IBAN = IBAN in col I`

## for example

## Inputs are

`name = ALI IBAN = 100100202`

the expected results
as following

```
`    date = 09/06/2024
    amount = 4000
    transaction code = Rent240614`
```

as shown in the pic below the highlighted row

[example 1 screen shoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ReZV.png)

the dates are not sorted
so i suggested to find max date meet the criteria - but i dont know how - :'(

I don't know how to write such a code
but i tried an array function but it is not working also

```
`   {=LOOKUP(2,1/($D$20=Table3[name]*$I$20=Table3[IBAN]),Table3[amount])}`
```

thank you

Comment: Find the newest date and bring back that row. Many posts on here have example code.

Answer (score -1):

if I understand you correctly ....

```
Sub test()
Dim rg As Range: Dim rg1 As Range: Dim rg2 As Range:
Dim nm As String: Dim iban As Long: Dim mx As Date

With ActiveSheet 'change if needed
Set rg = .Range("B2", .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With

nm = "ALI"
iban = 100100202

If Not rg.Find(nm, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
    With rg
        .Replace nm, True, xlWhole, , False, , False, False
        Set rg1 = .SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlLogical).Offset(0, 1)
        .Replace True, nm, xlWhole, , False, , False, False
    End With

    If Not rg1.Find(iban, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
        With rg1
            .Replace iban, True, xlWhole, , False, , False, False
            Set rg2 = .SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlLogical).Offset(0, -2)
            .Replace True, iban, xlWhole, , False, , False, False
        End With

        mx = Application.Max(rg2)
        Debug.Print "Date : " & mx
        Debug.Print "Amount : " & rg2.Find(mx).Offset(0, 5)
        Debug.Print "tr code : " & rg2.Find(mx).Offset(0, 6)
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

rg is the range of the column name.
then the code create rg1 range variable which cells has "ALI" value offseting (0,1) which is the iban column, so the rg1 is ALI's iban rows.

Then the code create rg2 where ALI's iban rows value is 100100202 offset (0,-2). So rg2 consist the dates of ALI where his iban is 100100202.

Then finally it debug.print the max value in rg2, the amount in the cell of max date found offset 0,5 and the tr code in the cell of max date found offset 0,6.

Please note that it may give unexpected result if there are more than one max date, such as if in your image, --for example--, Ali has two rows  "09/06/2024" in column A.